# How to create a reverse sort on an Excel array

Tags: arrays, excel, macos, vba

I have an array of 250 elements "myArray (1 to 250)". Is there a built-in excel for mac function that can give me a reverse number list? For example if I wanted to loop through the array from the last number to the first (250 to 1), the last number could have a pointer as the 1st item processed in my loop ie. 250 is the 1st processed, 249 is the second processed, 248 is the third, etc? My goal is using a built-in function vs creating a logic loop.

Comment: In VBA for PC, `For X = 250 to 1 Step  -1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a special requirement in VBA / MAC that precludes negative Step counters?

If not, just do something like:

```
For X = Ubound(myArray) to Lbound(myArray) Step -1
    Do Something
Next X
```